# Saving file java

Tags: java, performance, file, save, jfilechooser

Because the `File` object constructor needs a `String` to represent the path and considering other reasons, I chose to make a temporary file and when the user wants to save, to take the content of the temporary to the final file and ask the user to give the path at that time.
I have some code I will explain, but for many reasons, I think it's not one of the best solutions to do what I am trying to do.

```
public String FileSavePath() throws NullPointerException {

        boolean acceptable = false;
        String theFilepath = null;

        do {
            theFilepath = null;
            File f = null;
            JFileChooser FileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            if (FileChooser.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                theFilepath = FileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                f = FileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                //System.out.println(theFile);
                if (f.exists()) {
                    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "The file exists, overwrite?",
                            "Existing file", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
                    if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        acceptable = true;
                    }

                }
            } else {
                acceptable = true;
            }
        } while (!acceptable);
        saved=true;
        return theFilepath;

    }
```

And the method is called in the save function this way:

```
    FileChannel sourceChannel=null;
    FileChannel targetChannel=null;

                try
                {
                    try{
                        file=new File(FileSavePath());
                    }
                    catch(NullPointerException npe)
                    {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(temp).getChannel();
                    targetChannel = new FileOutputStream(file).getChannel();
                    targetChannel.transferFrom(sourceChannel, 0, 
                            sourceChannel.size());
                }
                catch(IOException ioe)
                {
                    System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
                }

                finally
                {   

                    try {
                        if (sourceChannel != null) {
                            sourceChannel.close();
                        }
                        if (targetChannel != null) {
                            targetChannel.close();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
```

Basically the mechanism is the following: All the data is saved to a temporary file. When the user wants to save, a `JFileChooser` appears and saves the path. Then the final file is iniatialized, the temporary data passed to the final file and that's it. The NPE is important to handle if the user did not chose a valid path or cancelled somewhere during the
What I am not sure of is if my code is efficent or if there were any ways to make it better.

P.S. Please don't bother telling that the exceptions are not handled yet, I know this, but I want to know if the basic idea would efficently do what is should.

Comment: You could just rename the temp file.  file.renameTo(newFile)

Comment: You shouldn't be *catching* `NullPointerException`. You should be avoiding generating it in the first place.

Comment: Why not just rename/move the temp file, rather than copying it to the new location?

Comment: Methods should start with a lower case in Java conventions -`fileSavePath`

Comment: lol seems legit. Thank you.
As an excuse, large code makes me sometimes not see simple ideas.

Comment: @cHao maybe he still needs the temp file...

Comment: `acceptable = (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)`

Comment: Still needed, but still easier to work with to files and switch each of the from final to temporary file each time

Comment: What i'm getting from the question is, the temp file is only there because there's no official name for the file yet.  Once there is, the temp file becomes unnecessary; one could just work with the "real" file instead, or (depending on the use case) start a new temp file for saving to a new location.

Comment: 1)  *"Because the File object constructor needs a String to represent the path and considering other reasons"*  Given 'the File object constructor needs a String' is not a good reason to avoid it, what are the 'other reasons'?  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @cHao Yep, what I will do is rename the temp and pass all the data to a new temp. Then each time user saves, I will switch between the files, making one the final, and the other the temporary. I might even use it for saving from time to time :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I still think the NPE is needed since the user may try to save without giving a file name, which would throw a NPE

Comment: @BujancaMihai: It will only throw an NPE if you still call new `File(FileSavePath())`. If instead you check the input *before* calling the constructor, as you should, there won't be an exception. You *really, really* shouldn't catch NPEs.

Comment: @JonSkeet well, I think I will just check if the string in different from null then. Thank you.

Comment: @cHao One more question, given the solution above. Will file.renameTo(newFile) also take my file to the desired path, since what I am saving is all the path? Or should I call a method that takes the file to the path?

Comment: @BujancaMihai: Renaming a file and moving it are basically the same thing.  You may need to close the file first and reopen it at the new location if you want to continue messing with it, but the move itself shouldn't require much if anything else.

Comment: You might consider [`Files.move`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) rather than `File.renameTo`, though.  Apparently it's more platform-independent and less flaky, and throws exceptions if it fails rather than just...failing.